# Dynamic reference variables (objects)?

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I want to create a new instance of an object every time I click a button on my page. The problem is the reference variable, if you look at this example?

```
<input value="Create person" onclick="CreateObject()" />

......

function CreateObject(){
var person = new Person("Carl", 18);
}
```

Everytime the function is called an instance of the object is created, with the same reference variable. I want the reference variables to be different every time the function is called (eg. "person1", "person2", "person3"). What shall I do?

Comment: Create an array instead of giving in to Them and their blasphemous ways(tm)?

Comment: Even though the variable is the same, it is a new variable each time because the scope is different each time. After CreateObject returns, the person variable (and object) is discarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use dynamic variable names **(not recommended)**:

```
function CreateObject()
{
    window['person' + CreateObject.counter++] = new Person("Carl", 18);
}

CreateObject.counter = 0;
```

---

Better (as [@delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395760/delnan) suggests) to use an array:

```
var people = [];

function CreateObject()
{
    var person = new Person("Carl", 18);
    people.push(person);
}
```